# PHP | Определение типа возвращаемого функцией значения через статическую переменную

Tags: php

Есть два класса, один наследуется другим. В первом классе есть функция возвращающая экземпляр определённого класса, она переходит и во второй, но так же возвращает экземпляр того же определённого класса. Существует ли способ сделать так, чтобы функция возвращала экземпляр другого класса, без надобности переопределения функции?
Как я представляю себе что-то подобное (частично псевдокод):

```
class a {}
class b {}

class aSystem
{
    static $type = a;
    public static function get(): static::$type
}

class bSystem
{
    static $type = b;
}
```

Comment: я думаю, тебе нужен интерфейс

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде этого не устроит?

```
class a {}
class b extends a {}

class aSystem
{
    static $type = a::class;
    public static function get(): a
    {
        return new static::$type;
    }
}

class bSystem extends aSystem
{
    static $type = b::class;
}

$s = new bSystem;
var_dump($s->get()); // object(b)#2 (0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Судья по вашему примеру вы создаете фарику классов с одним интерфейсом, чтоб к ним обращаться нужен класс фабричный метод. Пример:

```
interface Product {
    public function name();
}
class ProductA implements Product {
    public function name(){
        echo 'an A product';
    }
}
class ProductB implements Product {
    public function name(){
        echo 'a B product';
    }
}

abstract class SystemFabric
{
    public function render(){
        return $this->create();
    }
    
    public function create(){
        
    }
}

class aSystem extends SystemFabric
{
    public function create(){
        return new ProductA;
    }
}

class bSystem extends SystemFabric
{
    public function create(){
        return new ProductB;
    }
}


var_dump((new aSystem())->render()->name());
var_dump((new bSystem())->render()->name());
```

подробности про паттерна [фабричный метод](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/factory-method)

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]